# AWS Cognito using different Email Provider than SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I wonder if it is possible to swap SES for a custom Emailing Provider? I am already using one, and I don't want to configure another one because AWS Cognito needs that. Maybe there is a way to suppress all the emails coming out of AWS Cognito?

Thanks
Przemek

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Email provider to anything else than **AWS Cognito** or **AWS SES** – or **suppressing** the outgoing messages programmatically *was* **not possible**. The only possibility was to use a Lambda trigger to at least be able to modify the template of the message: `Custom Message Lambda Trigger`

*Until probably a few weeks/months ago:*

**[Custom sender Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html)**

> Amazon Cognito user pools provide two Lambda triggers CustomEmailSender and CustomSMSSender to enable third-party email and SMS notifications. You can Use your choice of SMS and email providers to send notifications to users from within your Lambda function code.

I did not find any release or change message on when they introduced those new triggers, but I am super happy I finally stumbled across this! I felt so much joy I almost cried.